# How to access a SQL Anywhere Server without a database to create one?

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

is it possible to connect to a SQL Anywhere Server without an existing database to create one. In SQL Anywhere Studio i always have to define an existing database.

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`dbinit`](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/3bc8f4f76c5f1014b7e0e816307e4ca4.html*loio3bc8f4f76c5f1014b7e0e816307e4ca4) utility to create a database without connecting to one. If you really want to connect to a SQL Anywhere server and execute the `CREATE DATABASE` statement yourself (which is all dbinit does), you can start the personal server (dbeng17) and use the [utility database](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sqla170/en/html/8130a50a6ce21014b560ab30a2c2c4b0.html*loio8130a50a6ce21014b560ab30a2c2c4b0), which is a "virtual" database that always exists. To do this, specify "DBN=utility_db" in your connection string.

Comment: Hi, but on the fly with SQL and a login it is not not possible?!?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I said in my answer that you can use SQL to do it by connecting to the utility database. What exactly are you trying that's not working?

Comment: Hi, tested it, works fine on production server too, not only personal server! Thanks